# sed how to replace from standard input

Tags: sed

I have to substitute (search and replace) a password field for files found in different directories.  All fields are formatted as: `field = value`

What I have attempted is:

```
grep -i  fieldofinterest /etc/filemod*/*| sed  's/[=].*$/ = myvalue/'
```

This seems to work but if I try to write, there is an error no input file given.

How can I do this substitution?

Comment: Do you want to change the files in place? This won't do that. Please edit the question to state more precisely what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the cuff:

```
grep -l fieldofinterest /etc/filemod*/* | while read filename; do
  sed 's/fieldofinterest.*/fieldofinterest = myvalue/' "$filename" > tmp && mv tmp "$filename"
done
```

That gathers `grep -l` the filenames that contain *fieldofinterest* and passes them to the `while` loop for `sed` replacement via a temporary file. If your sed has `-i` you can simplify it to:

```
grep -l fieldofinterest /etc/filemod*/* | while read filename; do
  sed -i 's/fieldofinterest.*/fieldofinterest = myvalue/' "$filename" 
done
```